# Stata: selecting the reference variables in an interaction

Tags: regression, stata

When I run the following regression,

```
reg subject inSchool#treatment#male
```

I get comparisons in reference to inSchool=0, treatment=0, and male=0, but I would like to be able to change the reference variables.

For example I would like to have all the comparisons done in reference to inSchool=1,treatment=0, and male=1.

I have used the following characteristic command but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
char inSchool[omit] 1 male[omit] 1
```

Am I having a syntax issue or is there no way to choose which variable to omit using #

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help fvvarlist`:

> You can specify the base level of a factor variable by using the `ib.` operator.

Comment: Thanks this one was really driving me crazy!